# Animação no Android Travando

Tags: android

Estou fazendo uma animação no Android Studio para um app, porém ao executar ela    executa com uns travamentos como se fosse perca de frames. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

```
package com.example.lucas.tostudy;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    }

    Thread splashTread;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        StartAnimations();
    }


    private void StartAnimations() {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
        anim.reset();
        ConstraintLayout c=(ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.cons_layout);
        c.clearAnimation();
        c.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogoEscrito);
        iv2.clearAnimation();
        iv2.startAnimation(anim);

        splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    // Splash screen pause time
                    while (waited < 5000) {
                        sleep(100);
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    SplashScreen.this.finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } finally {
                    SplashScreen.this.finish();
                }

            }
        };
        splashTread.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Eu tive um problema parecido, que a thread dava uns "lag", eu substitui por esse codigo, e ajudou no meu caso, poderia testar?
 `private Runnable t1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
             // Coloque aqui seu codigo.
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };`
E depois no onCreate pra chamar a thread isso:  `new Thread(t1).start();`

Comment: O problema persistiu.

Comment: Resolvi o problema usando as dicas desse post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726660/android-animation-reduce-stutter-choppy-lag

Comment: Resolvi o problema usando as dicas desse post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726660/android-animation-reduce-stutter-choppy-lag